# OSX implementation of main() and conflicting data types with POSIX getopt() in C?

Tags: c, macos, posix, darwin

I have found the system specific definition and recommended usage practice of `main()` *hardly documented* in context of POSIX `getopt()` in OSX/Darwin, such as shown in this little test I wrote:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main (int argc, const char *argv[])//this is *not* MY "prototype" of main - it is OSX!
{
    int   opt = 0;    
    int ch;
    char *cvalue = NULL;

    while ((ch = getopt (argc, argv, "d:")) != -1)
        switch (ch){
            case 'd':
                cvalue = optarg;
                opt = 1;
                break;
            case '?':
                if (optopt == 'd')
                     printf ("Option -%c requires an argument.\n", optopt);
                break;
            default:
                abort();
        }
    if(opt)printf("optarg = %s\n", optarg);
    return 0;
}
```

The compilers issue the following, rather intimidating warnings:

gcc:

```
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:15: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘getopt’ from incompatible pointer type
```

clang:

```
test.c:15:32: warning: passing 'const char **' to parameter of type 'char *const *'
  discards qualifiers in nested pointer types [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
while ((ch = getopt (argc, argv, "d:")) != -1)
                           ^~~~
 /usr/include/unistd.h:548:31: note: passing argument to parameter here
 int  getopt(int, char * const [], const char *) __DARWIN_ALIAS(getopt);
                              ^
```

AFAIK, char pointers to immutable arrays are indeed *incompatible* with immutable pointers to
character arrays. There is not much I can do unless changing the `main()` definition to
supply arguments as required by `POSIX` `getopt()`:

```
int main(int argc, char *const argv [] ){ ... }
```

or according to the C standard (as defined in section 5.1.2.2.1 of C11 draft standard n1570) and  [described in this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/what-should-main-return-in-c-and-c):

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[] ){ ... }
```

This silences the compiler warnings, but makes me wonder: although *same manufacturer* implements both C and POSIX, *forking* from their prototype of `main()` which seemingly conflicts with their *hosted environment implementation* of POSIX C gives an impression of solving the problem.

As I am developing a set of UNIX *command line tools* in OSX, all of which must reliably *redirect*, *pipe*, stay *interactive*, use *files* 
etc. in rather complex chains and critical conditions, I need a bit deeper understanding for what reason the OSX `main()` should take such argument types. Has someone worked with this specific implementation of `main()`, and which would the safe procedure of solving the described issue in  OSX/Darwin, without inducing risks of UB or otherwise compromised functionality? This is as far as my efforts have brought me - either in conflict with the system, or with the C standard. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your prototype for `main()` is incorrect. It is supposed to be `int main (int argc, char *argv[])`, or equivalently `int main (int argc, char **argv)`. Note the lack of `const`. See c11 draft standard n1570: *5.1.2.2.1 Program startup 2 If they are declared, the parameters to the main function shall obey the following constraints: [...]— The parameters argc and argv and the strings pointed to by the argv array shall
be modifiable by the program, and retain their last-stored values between program startup and program termination.* **Shall be modifiable**.

Comment: Thanks for your kind comment, @EOF. It might have skipped your attention that I haven't invented a goofy "homebrew" `main()` "prototype", but used the OSX prototype of `main()`, @EOF. I'm grateful for your pointing me at the same C standard I'm also quoting in my question. To put it short: I'm either in conflict with the system or with the standard - I hope there is a solution - that's what my question is about. Thanks, nevertheless.

Comment: I wonder why `getopt()` is declared to take an array of modifiable strings -- why would it ever need to write to them?

Comment: Found my answer here: https://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-hackers/2011-February/034407.html

Comment: What do you mean "The OSX prototype of main"?  I can't find anywhere that OSX defines a prototype for main.  The only one I can find on my OSX system is `int main(int argc, char **argv )` in /usr/include/tidy/tidy.h

Comment: Thanks @Chris Dodd. In practically any example code for OSX you can find it. Even if you worked with any version of *Xcode Tools*, be it command line or GUI version, `int main(int argc, const char * argv[])` is what the **system** generated template looks like, in any version since 10+ years, or in any Apple documentation involving `main()`.

Comment: I did a web search for 'OSX example main C', and can't find a SINGLE example that uses `const char` -- EVERY ONE is either `main(int, char **)` or `main()` (though there are some broken ones with a `void` return type.)

Comment: Thanks for your input, @Chris Dodd. By no means do I want to contradict your expertise or challenge your good will.  I would have immediately agreed with you, because it is logical. I'm dealing with things other people have invented and poorly documented. Please be so kind to look at [this](https://books.google.hr/books?id=YpwXYYvxqwkC&pg=PA154&lpg=PA154&dq=osx+main(int+argc,+const+char+*argv%5B%5D)&source=bl&ots=mw-PbGbBoM&sig=HjGOaVfOYJ9YdWa7WjM2zePZZmM&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjcr6CU8Z3NAhVGEJoKHT-SDt8Q6AEIRDAI#v=onepage&q=osx%20main(int%20argc%2C%20const%20char%20*argv%5B%5D)&f=false).

Comment: @user3078414 You are correct. You should report as a bug to Apple.

Answer (score 0):

It's your code, so it's your prototype. MacOS X may *suggest* what main looks like, but you're not bound by that. Anything conforming to the C standard will work. So go and add the missing parameter.

Comment: Thanks @gnasher729. In *my* code I have also gone for the option of forking from _OSX_ prototype of `main()` because it's the easiest way to get rid of the compiler warnings. I posted this question hoping to get more information from professional people who have encountered this problem. The test example posted is how OSX would suggest doing it by the book.